# C# Aes ecb pkcs5pad

Tags: c#, php, encryption, aes

i need a AES function to encrypt/decrypt with model ecb, PKCS5Padding using an symmetric key(128 bits created with AES parameters)

but I'm having some problems with this since
im noob in c#

in php is approximate to this and i need create in ASP.net(c#):

pkcs5 pading:

```
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
```

function to encode AES(ecb - pkcs5pad), **$data is the data do encode**:

```
function base64_encode_encrypt_aes_ecb_pkcs5pad($data, $sim_key) {
    return trim ( base64_encode ( mcrypt_encrypt ( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $sim_key, pkcs5_pad ( $data, mcrypt_get_block_size ( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB ) ), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv ( mcrypt_get_iv_size ( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB ), MCRYPT_RAND ) ) ) );
}
```

To get sim_key(symetric key)

```
function gen_sim_key() {
    return substr ( md5 ( uniqid ( microtime () ) ), 0, 16 );
}
```

can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library seems to provide what you need:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

From the feature list:

*Symmetric key paddings: ISO10126d2, ISO7816d4, PKCS#5/7, TBC, X.923, and Zero Byte.*